# VagrantとVirtualBoxでの仮想マシンの作成時に poweroff (virtualbox) と表示されてしまう

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

VagrantとVirtualBoxを使用して仮想マシンを作成しようとしていますが、エラーが出てしまい先に進めません。

**参考にした書籍:**
「ビジネスサイトを作って学ぶWordPressの教科書」19ページ

PCはマックを使用しており、著者の本の正誤表はすでに確認しております。

以下の通りコマンドを実行しても poweroff (virtualbox)と表示されてしまいます。
running(virtualbox)と表示されるのが理想です。

**実行時のログ (全体):**

```
Last login: Thu Nov 11 14:34:52 on ttys000

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
kei-no-MacBook-Air:~ kei$ cd /Users/kei/Desktop/
kei-no-MacBook-Air:Desktop kei$  mkdir pacificmall
kei-no-MacBook-Air:Desktop kei$  cd pacificmall
kei-no-MacBook-Air:pacificmall kei$  vagrant init prime-strategy/kusanagi-wp5 --box-version 1.0
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
kei-no-MacBook-Air:pacificmall kei$ ls
Vagrantfile
kei-no-MacBook-Air:pacificmall kei$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'prime-strategy/kusanagi-wp5'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'prime-strategy/kusanagi-wp5' version '1.0' is up to date...
==> default: There was a problem while downloading the metadata for your box
==> default: to check for updates. This is not an error, since it is usually due
==> default: to temporary network problems. This is just a warning. The problem
==> default: encountered was:
==> default: 
==> default: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
==> default: 
==> default: If you want to check for box updates, verify your network connection
==> default: is valid and try again.
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: pacificmall_default_1636615684491_31898
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
The IP address configured for the host-only network is not within the
allowed ranges. Please update the address used to be within the allowed
ranges and run the command again.

  Address: 192.168.33.10
  Ranges: 192.168.56.0/21

Valid ranges can be modified in the /etc/vbox/networks.conf file. For
more information including valid format see:

  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly
kei-no-MacBook-Air:pacificmall kei$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

default                   poweroff (virtualbox)

The VM is powered off. To restart the VM, simply run `vagrant up`
kei-no-MacBook-Air:pacificmall kei$
```

Vagrantfile

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "prime-strategy/kusanagi-wp5"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Ansible, Chef, Docker, Puppet and Salt are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

ホストオンリーネットワークのために設定されたIPアドレスは、許された範囲内にない。
許された範囲内にあるように用いられたアドレスをアップデートし、再びコマンドを実行してください。

アドレス：192.168.33.10
範囲：192.168.56.0/21

有効な範囲は、/etc/vbox/networks.conf ファイルにおいて修正できる。
詳細については、有効なフォーマット見る。：

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

と出てきますが、方法がわかりません、どなたか分かる方はいらっしゃいますか？

Comment: PC 上にウイルスバスター等のセキュリティソフトはインストールされていますか？

Comment: もともと入っているものを使用しています。

Answer (score 2):

Vagrantfileのこの部分

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

を下記に変えたところ、うまく行くと教えていただきました。

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.10"
```